# Converting Kotlin app to Xamarin.Android application

Tags: c#, android, kotlin, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am trying to translate a Kotlin (Android) application to Xamarin.Android application. I came across a function and not able to figure out what would be equivalent C# code would be.

```
fun loadDrawable(
    activity: Activity,
    imageUrl: String?,
    @DrawableRes defaultImage: Int,
    onLoaded: (image: Drawable) -> Unit) {

val imageToLoad = if (imageUrl.isNullOrEmpty()) defaultImage else imageUrl

Glide.with(activity)
        .load(imageToLoad)
        .error(defaultImage)
        .centerCrop()
        .into<CustomTarget<Drawable>>(object : CustomTarget<Drawable>() {

            override fun onResourceReady(resource: Drawable, transition: Transition<in Drawable>?) {
                onLoaded(resource)
            }

            override fun onLoadCleared(placeholder: Drawable?) {
                placeholder?.let { onLoaded(it) }
            }
        })
 }
```

In the above function, I am not able to convert the last parameter (**onLoaded: (image: Drawable) -> Unit**) to the function.

This is how I am currently calling the above function in Kotlin

```
        loadDrawable(requireActivity(), null, R.drawable.bg_default) {
        _backgroundManager?.drawable = it
    }
```

I would really appreciate if someone can help me figure out how to convert this code (or something equivalent in functionality in C#)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve the same functionality using action delegate

```
Action<Drawable> onLoaded
```

Comment: Please littlebit briefly explain the answer.@nafr1